# Vuetify how to make v-row floating on top of other elements and with fixed position but still preserve the width of parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I'm using Vuetify and I'm trying to make element inside v-row floating and fixed but still preserve the width of parent element.

here is my code :

```
 <v-container>
                            <v-row class="mb-3" style="position:fixed; z-index:999;" >
                                <v-col cols="12">
                                    <v-hover>
                                        <template v-slot="{ hover }">
                                            <v-card max-height="50" class="prioritas" :elevation="hover ? 17 : 6">
                                                <v-card dark class="d-flex justify-center
                                                align-self-center kelA" color="blue" max-width="150" height="30">
                                                    <span class="mt-1">
                                                        Kelurahan Angin
                                                    </span>
                                                </v-card>
                                                <v-row style="margin-top:-40px">
                                                    <v-col cols="3">
                                                        <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
                                                    </v-col>
                                                    <v-col cols="3">
                                                        <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
                                                    </v-col>
                                                    <v-col cols="3">
                                                        <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
                                                    </v-col>
                                                    <v-col cols="3">
                                                        <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
                                                    </v-col>
                                                </v-row>
                                            </v-card>
                                        </template>
                                    </v-hover>
                                </v-col>
                            </v-row>
<v-container>
```

it is floating on top other elements but it doesn't preserve the width , it shrank.
here it is:
[image: result]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried "width:100%" ?
Have you tried "width:100%" ?
Have you tried "width:100%" ?

Comment: it will overflow the screen